# executing SSIS package hangs when called in C#

Tags: c#, ssis

there;

I created a SSIS package which loads CSV into database. The package is called in a C# console application which is set as scheduled task in a server.

The problem I having is that the package hangs during validation stage:

> Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column
>   "ReadingType" with a length of 50 to database column "ReadingType"
>   with a length of 2.

There is no problem loading same data from development machine.

Can some give a clue what might causes this?

Cheers,

Qiuwei

Comment: Check ReadingType column  type on the server env. It seems you schema on the server side maybe different from the dev env.

Comment: There are only three possibilities that I know of:   1)  the CSV data is different on the two servers, 2) the destination table structure is different on the two servers or 3) the package is different on the two servers.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 1)the schema is different, but it should affect the data importing in this case. When I run from my dev machine, the data still goes to the same server/database. 2) CSV data is the same because the package in dev machine and  UAT server are set to the same data source.3)I am going to recompile the package and re-deploy the package.